# understanding sed regex with numbered groups

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm trying to understand this sed regex.

```
       sed 's/.*\(ADDR=[^|]*\) |.*/\1/'
```

If I'm not wrong, the above will search for the pattern `ADDR=<something>` anywhere in a line and
replace it with the first group.  I don't get the meaning of **[^|]** here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Zero or more characters that aren't `|` (vertical bar character)".

Comment: `[^|]` matches anything other than a `|`. `^` in character class negates the character class

Comment: In order for the substitution to succeed  two string must be present and in order `ADDR=` and `|`. The successful group returned may contain nothing other than the matching string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\(ADDR=[^|]*\) |.*/\1/`

Here

- `[^|]` matches anything other than `|` and the quantifier `*` quantifies zero or more occurrences of it. `^` in character class negates the character class.
- `|` matches the character `|`

**NOTE** In `sed`  metacharacters like `|` `(` `)` etc will lose its meaning so `|` is not an alternation but matches a `|` character. If you want to treat the metacharacters as such, then `-r` (extended regular expression) will do so (with GNU `sed`; use `-E` with BSD `sed`). Or escape `\|`.

**Example:**

```
$ echo "hello ADDR= hello | world " | sed 's/.*\(ADDR=[^|]*\) |.*/\1/'
ADDR= hello
```

Here `(ADDR=[^|]*\)` matches from `ADDR= hello` which contains anything other than `|`.

Comment: *"In `sed` all metacharacters in regex will [lose] [their] meaning"* -- that's hardly correct; it's just a more constrained regex dialect. It certainly has metacharacters, such as `.*[\ `.

Comment: @tripleee I have edited answer to correct that misleading sentence

Answer (score 2):

`[^...]`    Matches any single character that is not in the class.

`|`         The vertical bar separates two or more alternatives. A match occurs if any of the alternatives is satisfied. For example, `gray|grey` matches both `gray` and `grey`.

`[^|]` matches anything other than a `|`. `^` in character class negates the character class while `|` is loose it's actual meaning when using with `sed`.

Comment: You may note that within a character class every metacharacter including `|` will loose its meaning

Comment: Yes certainly @nu11p01n73R

Comment: Also the `|` here doesnt mean an alternation as within sed it looses its meaning as well which is treated as a single character `|`