# Converting a sed regular expression to python code

Tags: python, regex, sed

I can understand the following sed regular expression.

```
 sed 's/.*\(SNAP=[^|]*\) |.*/\1/' | sort | uniq -c > $log.snaps
```

I have the task of converting this bash line to Python code. What is best way to do this? 
Simply invoke `os.system(cmd)` with above as *cmd* ?
Or use the Python `re` module ?
Any pseudo code is most welcome. :)

Comment: Depends what you mean by "best" and what exactly your goal is.  Of course you *could* just throw it into `os.system()`, but then why are you bothering with Python at all?  If you want to reimplement it in native Python, then yes, use the `re` module and the `sorted()` builtin; there's no `uniq` equivalent but it's fairly trivial to implement.

Comment: @lak could you provide an example of what the above code would do?

Comment: It basically excludes content after it encounters |  check the hello example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965276/understanding-sed-regex-with-numbered-groups   @AdamRosenfield, I'm looking for performance. It have 10-15 sed statements like this on a large file. Wondering which is the proper way to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked for the best way, I'm just giving you a simple one. You could surely optimize it.
But still, it is worth testing with your constraints, since invoking a shell takes some time.
It should be worth noting that pipes in shell might be a great way to have faster code, since `sed` can start to work whithout waiting for `cat` to finish. `sort` will also be able to begin its work but obviously will only output when sed is done working. So it is a great way to use your `CPU` during your IOs and should be considered as a low effort/good performance solution.
I've tried with  a simple example, but you will get the idea :

In `test` :

```
love
lol
loki
loki
ki
loutre
poutre
```

Simple bash command, looking like yours :

```
cat test | sed 's/lo\(.*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq
```

Outputs :

```
ki
l
poutre
utre
ve
```

Now let's try to do the same in python :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

s = """love
lol
loki
loki
ki
loutre
poutre"""

arr = s.split('\n')                                             # sed iterates on each line
arr = map((lambda line: re.sub(r'lo(.*)$', r'\1', line)), arr)  # sed
arr = set(arr)                                                  # uniq
arr = sorted(list(arr))                                         # sort

print '\n'.join(arr)                                            # output it
```

This could also be written in a ugly line of code :

```
print '\n'.join(sorted(list(set(map((lambda line: re.sub(r'lo(.*)$', r'\1', line)), s.split('\n'))))))
```

Comment: I don't think I would come up with a solution using map and lambda :) Thanks a lot @Jerska

Comment: Well, although it is working, you should have a look to my edit before starting to use such a solution.

Comment: Yes, Just read your recent edit, will consider them before using.